# Angularjs - is there a way to programatically click on an HTML <select> element?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I've seen a javascript solution that goes a little something like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('selectId')
select.click();
```

Is there an AngularJS approach/best practice to the same thing?  (Off the top of my head, you'd wrap the above code in an ng-click)

Comment: Why you require to click it, call the handler function directly

Comment: There can be any number of reasons why someone may want to `trigger` a event on an element programatically. That's why the trigger functions exist in JavaScript, jQuery , Prototype and Angular and so on..

Comment: I'm writing an HTML 5 hybrid app using Ionic for iOS/Android.  The <select> element is inside a field in a form (a rectangular row with 16px padding on all sides).  Our UX spec is calling for any touch event on any part of the row to trigger the platform's native picker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. Here's the angular equivalent of what you have in JavaScript

```
angular.element('#selectId').trigger('click');
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tcVhN/173/)

Comment: This won't work...JQlite doesn't have a trigger function. Any DOM manipulation should also occur inside a directive. You'll need to wrap your angular.element as a JQuery selector to use the trigger method.

Comment: Works just fine.. check example.

Comment: ahhh...because Angular recognizes jquery is included. It works...but that's not how to use angular....not even in a module...to each his own

Answer (score 1):

Any DOM manipulation in angular should occur inside of a directive.

View

```
<div id="selectId" clickMe>content</div>
```

Inside of a directive the link function triggers after the view is compiled. The second parameter in the link function is the element which the directive is placed on, this gives performance benefits since there is no need to traverse the dom. It is a JQlite element which you can directly call methods on.

Directive

```
app.directive('click-me', function(){
  return{
    link(scope, el, attr){
       $(el).trigger('click');
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not replace to programatically click. To be able to do this via a directive, you also have to show how to add directive dynamically! the whole purpose is to be able to do this in run time. Plus why complicate something this simple , when you can trigger a click.. also.. Triggering Click event is NOT dom manipulation

Comment: where would angular.element('#selectId').trigger('click'); if not in a directive?

Comment: anywhere in code where you want to trigger a click.   angular  is a global object :)  You can type that statement in chrome console if you want and it will work

Comment: Attaching DOM manipulation to the global angular object seems like poor architecture to me.

Comment: Again, clicking is not manipulating, and if anything this will be bad code design, and not architecture.  Sometimes over doing design patterns is bad. Code readability trumps  over engineering.

Comment: If you're using jquery in angular it's for DOM manipluation. We're not clicking, we're triggering a click on the DOM... Separating responsibilities makes for much easier to manage code. Dom Manipulations should not exist in controllers, services or anywhere else but in directives.

Comment: Agree on all counts, but in any case just making it a directive does not solve the question here.  Look at his comment where he explains why he wants to trigger a click and then explain in your answer how to achieve that with the directive. Not saying you can't , but as it stands your answer is incomplete.

Comment: You're answer takes a jquery approach. Angular is an opinionated framework...this would be the correct angular approach. I don't see it as an incomplete answer. Not to mention Jqlite which angular uses doesn't have a trigger function.